# Movable Do vs Fixed Do

Tags: performing, ear-training, solfege

I'm trying to train my ear, I had 2 teachers before, one of them recommends me to use scale degree in context of the key (which is basically movable do) and the other teacher recommends me fixed do.

I don't think the teacher who uses fixed do has perfect pitch but her ears seems really good. I was playing a piece (which I don't think she's heard before) I played one wrong note and she immediately says shouldn't it be this note?

my other teacher who uses movable do can hear harmonic progression very well. in real time also. but I don't know his ability to transcribe notes in real time.

now I think that movable do is superior because let's face it. fixed do is for the people who has perfect pitch but I'm going to give the benefit of the doubt because she says that you have to use fixed do for a very long time. I think she may have developed semi perfect pitch. like she can only have perfect pitch when it's only on the piano. she cannot reproduce notes or things that people who actually have perfect pitch can do.

while that seems nice but that means I literally have to sing everything I learn in fixed for a long time.

why I think movable do is practical is because well here

this guy explains this perfectly
2:25 for the main point.

Comment: What is your question exactly? I personally recommend both fixed do solfège *and* scale-degree singing. (Just don't mix fixed and movable, because you'll stumble over the syllables and never learn anything.)

Comment: I just giving you what my thoughts are in each concept and I wanted to hear what you guys think in what to prefer

Comment: Then i think you should as this directly (PS: primarily opinion based questions are off-topic, so try to be specific!)

Comment: @Richard - yes, it's the same as my question of two and a half years ago.

Comment: The simple answer is do as you teacher says. If you are at a level where you take lessons from a teacher, do exactly as he/she says. A good teacher will guide you along in learning things you did not even know existed, even less knew you needed, and in a progression matched to your progress.

Comment: @ghellquist - in all the years I've been a teacher, I've NEVER expected any student to 'do as I say'. There are far too many teachers around like that. I expect students to question everything - and if I don't know the answer, I'll damned well have it, and extra explanation, ready for the next lesson. With an issue such as this, I could spend a couple of lessons going through the ins and outs of each, but 'because I say so' will never be the case. I suffered years of lessons with such teachers, and it's a wonder I ever became a muso...

Comment: @tim - there is a place where you think too much. Learning music is learning a skill. I agree that a teacher should be able to explain, but I also think that sometimes I as a student simply has to do. There was an old film, Karate Kid, with a famous training of "wax on, wax off". It was not initially explained at all, the explanation came later once the move was perfected. Sometimes, when learning, it is better to simply do and not to think too much. Well, at least in my personal experience, and it might help the OP. Might not.

Answer (score 0):

In some places in the world they use solfège as the note names. So where we say c, d, e they say [do re me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solf%C3%A8ge#Fixed_do_solf%C3%A8ge). In this context fixed do makes sense. You wouldn't want to call the tonic c in every key right? But in countries where we use note names c, d, e etc I think movable do just makes more sense.

With fixed do in some countries they don't change the note name if there is sharp or a flat and for me, this just doesn't make sense.

I think as far as ear training goes, learning what a scale degree sounds like in the context of the key center is very useful. movable do helps you learn this as where fix do may not.